# how to use logarithmic differentiation on a multi term fraction?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I have been stumped on this problem for hours now I just can't seem to get close to an acceptable answer things just keep please help explain how this is done...

Use logarithmic differentiation to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.
$$y = \frac{(x + 1)(x − 8)}{(x − 1)(x + 8)}, x > 8$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$\ln(y)=\ln(x-8)+\ln(x+1)-\ln(x+8)-\ln(x-1)$$

$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x-8}+\frac{1}{x+1}-...$$

Can you finish it?